# Install Sohpos VPN/Open VPN on GCE ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, google-cloud

I am new to using Linux, and am trying to install the Sophos SSL VPN Client/Open VPN on a Google Compute Engine (GCE) running ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20210224.  The instructions I have seen all refer to using the web browser to go and download the file containing the configuration, however GCEs don't have the gui installed, and I have tried several thing to install a simple gui to no avail.  I imagine that there is a way to do all of this from the command line, but am not sure how.

Basically, I would like to install all of this from the command line, and then have the vm connect to the vpn on startup.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have the URL of the installation file(s), then you can use `wget`.

Comment: The web browser runs on your desktop/client and not on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like the Sophos VPN client is actually just an OpenVPN wrapper, it's probably easiest to install the `openvpn` package and use that instead of the Sophos-wrapped one.  You can then download the configuration file from a URL using `curl -o OUTPUT-FILE URL` (after installing the `curl` package) and then copy it or move it into the right place.